# Adding status to a query not working

Tags: categories, query, status

Ive been using a query to pull in the amount of posts from a given category no problem. But i now want to pull in from a given status but no matter what i try its just not working quite right.

This is the code that works without the status..

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(exp_category_posts.entry_id) AS post_count

FROM exp_category_posts

WHERE cat_id = {category_id}
"}{post_count}{/exp:query}
```

And i want to add in the status.. which ive tried with the following, but this isnt quite right,

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(exp_category_posts.entry_id) AS post_count

FROM exp_category_posts 

JOIN exp_channel_entries

WHERE cat_id = '{category_id}' AND status = 'open'
 "}{post_count}{/exp:query}
```

Anyone any suggestions?

thanks
B.

Answer (score 5):

A `JOIN` requires an `ON` clause too. Also, it's `exp_channel_titles`, not `exp_channel_entries`. Try this on for size as the `sql` parameter:

```
SELECT COUNT(cp.entry_id) AS post_count
FROM exp_category_posts cp
JOIN exp_channel_titles t
ON cp.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE t.status IN ('Open', 'open')
AND cp.cat_id = '{category_id}'
```

If you want to add more statuses to the list, just add them inside the brackets, ie `('Open', 'open', 'draft', 'foo')`.

Comment: Im presuming the cp is short for category_posts, whats the t short for? just trying to understand it.. ;-)

Comment: I'm aliasing the table names in the `FROM` clause: `long_table_name alias` or `long_table_name AS alias`. Saves you typing the whole table name for each column you're using.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question. :)